# Reading Response from HttpServletResponse

Tags: spring-boot

I implements HandlerInterceptor to log and do some logic before and after any HTTP request in my spring boot application using

```
@Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws IOException {}

@Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
            ModelAndView modelAndView) throws IOException {}
```

every thing going fine, but I can not read the response from HttpServletResponse to log in the table.

Is there any way to read the response in postHandle method from HttpServletResponse ?

Comment: You cannot do this in a `HandlerInterceptor` only in a filter. You can only read the request and response once. If you are logging it in the `HandlerInterceptor` the response has been already written and the client won't see it, hence breaking things. You can only do this in a filter and wrap the request/response with a wrapper that allows for reading it multiple times.

Comment: Thanks Deinum, Do you know if there is an example that's show how to handle HandlerInterceptor with Filter ?

Comment: No as that is not possible. Those are totally different components.

Comment: Thanks, Do you have any idea if there is an alternative of `HandlerInterceptor` , so I can do some logic before and after http request (for logging purposes)

Comment: I already gave you that, a servlet `Filter`.

Comment: Thanks Deinum, I can now read the Response Body using Filter Interface, but I still have an issue, when I try to request an method that's have @RequestBody, below exception is thrown :
 org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing
This happened when I added Filter logic

Comment: Becauser you probably didn't wrap the request and response in a request- and response wrapper that allows for multiple reading. You just moved the logic without modification. The question you ask regarding the filter has been asked numerous times before, so I would suggest a search (or use the Spring provided request and response wrappers).